# JavaScript: как вызвать окно в браузере для разрешения определения местоположения?

Tags: javascript, геолокация

Нужно запрашивать разрешение на определение местоположения в браузере, в случае если оно у пользователя отключено (триггерить сам запрос браузера на разрешение определения местоположения каждый раз при нажатии на кнопку, в случае если в браузере стоит запрет на определение местоположения)
Как это сделать?

```
if(navigator.geolocation){
                    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                        function (position){

                        },
                        function (error){

                        //здесь должно открываться окно браузера с просьбой разрешить определение местоположения                               

                        }
                    );
                }
```

Comment: при первом вызове `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` браузер сам запросит разрешение у пользователя, если есть соответствующие настройки

Comment: Да, но если у пользователя стоит для этого сайта всегда запрещать или уже отвечал "нет", то нужно повторно при каждом нажатии на кнопку триггерить разрешение определения местоположения

Comment: В общем случае ничего нельзя сделать

Comment: Как же браузер может тебе разрешить, если пользователь уже запретил?) Так нельзя делать

Comment: Браузер не должен разрешать, он должен повторно запросить у пользователя разрешение

Comment: можно выводить пользователю сообщение с просьбой включить геолокацию

Comment: Так если при нажатии на кнопку, Вы не пробовали свою функцию обернуть в событие onclick?